# Phonegap Facebook Plugin and Google Analytics plugin bite each other

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

For a new Cordova/Phonegap-project (created using cordova 5.5.1.) I added the Phonegap Facebook Plugin (first cloning it to hard disk as per their instructions) using the correct Facebook App ID and Name. Then I added the Android project and I was able to run it on my android device.

Then I added Daniel Wilson's Google Analytics Plugin. When running android I get the following error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    [at etc,
    at etc.]
:dexDebug FAILED
```

How to solve this? I think it has something to do with the library android.support.annotations, but I don't know where it is added and how to prevent or change something there.

Steps to reproduce:
Install cordova 5.5.1. Then run the following CLI-commands:

```
cordova create NewApp com.apps.NewApp
cd NewApp
git clone https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git
cordova -d plugin add phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="1234567689" --variable APP_NAME="FB-appname"
cordova platform add android
cordova plugin add https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin.git

cordova run android
```

Comment: I would recommend that you add your solution as an answer instead of editing the question :)

Comment: updated the question and added the answer. Thanks for pointing this out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: I managed to get to work using Android Studio. I removed a file after adding the plugins to the new project before adding the android platform. So first:

```
cordova create NewApp com.apps.NewApp
cd NewApp
git clone https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git
cordova -d plugin add phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="1234567689" --variable APP_NAME="FB-appname"
cordova plugin add https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin.git
```

And then I removed the file MyApp\plugins\com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect\platforms\android\FacebookLib\libs\android-support-v4.jar

After that I also edited the file MyApp\plugins\com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect\platforms\android\FacebookLib\AndroidManifest.xml by changing min-sdk-version 9 to min-sdk-version 10 in order to prevent a warning later on.

Then I added the android project using cordova:

```
cordova platform add android
```

I opened Android Studio, chose the MyApp\platforms\android folder under File->Open and let Android Studio add the gradle wrapper. When building I got the error complaining about missing the android-support library.

```
Error:(27, 30) error: package android.support.v4.app does not exist
```

So I added it manually in Android Studio: File->Project Structure -> MyApp-FacebookLib -> Dependencies -> green plus sign -> 1 Library dependency -> support-v4 and press OK!

That did the trick.